# Execution failed for task ':flutter_libserialport:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'

Tags: android, flutter

I'm using the flutter_libserial package, it works on windows and linux but when i try to run it on android it doesn't want ot work anymore and gave me these errors, i've checked before using the package and it said that It's for android too. Anyway if you know why this error appear and how to resolve it it will be so glad, so this is the error:

```
[   +1 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +3 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':flutter_libserialport:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
[        ] > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `C:\Users\lucam\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_libserialport-0.3.0\android\.cxx\Debug\134n544x\arm64-v8a'
[        ]   [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/serialport.dir/cf3e89b45cd7f3a8a7f5136962e6f0f9/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c.o
[        ]   FAILED: CMakeFiles/serialport.dir/cf3e89b45cd7f3a8a7f5136962e6f0f9/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c.o 
[        ]   C:\Users\lucam\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\23.1.7779620\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21
--gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot    
-DLIBSERIALPORT_ATBUILD -Dserialport_EXPORTS -IC:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/android/libserialport
-IC:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/android/libserialport/../../third_party/libserialport -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong      
-no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wshadow -MD -MT
CMakeFiles/serialport.dir/cf3e89b45cd7f3a8a7f5136962e6f0f9/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c.o -MF CMakeFiles\serialport.dir\cf3e89b45cd7f3a8a7f5136962e6f0f9\third_party\libserialport\linux_termios.c.o.d -o
CMakeFiles/serialport.dir/cf3e89b45cd7f3a8a7f5136962e6f0f9/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c.o -c C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c    
[   +1 ms]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:43:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'TCGETS2'
[        ]           return TCGETS2;
[        ]                  ^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:52:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'TCSETS2'
[   +1 ms]           return TCSETS2;
[        ]                  ^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:61:9: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'struct termios2'
[        ]           return sizeof(struct termios2);
[        ]                  ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:61:23: note: forward declaration of 'struct termios2'
[        ]           return sizeof(struct termios2);
[        ]                                ^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:75:10: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct termios2'
[        ]           if (term->c_ispeed != term->c_ospeed)
[        ]               ~~~~^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:71:9: note: forward declaration of 'struct termios2'
[        ]           struct termios2 *term = (struct termios2 *) data;
[        ]                  ^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:75:28: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct termios2'
[        ]           if (term->c_ispeed != term->c_ospeed)
[        ]                                 ~~~~^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:71:9: note: forward declaration of 'struct termios2'
[        ]           struct termios2 *term = (struct termios2 *) data;
[        ]                  ^
[   +2 ms]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:78:14: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct termios2'
[        ]                   return term->c_ispeed;
[   +1 ms]                          ~~~~^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:71:9: note: forward declaration of 'struct termios2'
[        ]           struct termios2 *term = (struct termios2 *) data;
[        ]                  ^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:88:6: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct termios2'
[        ]           term->c_cflag &= ~CBAUD;
[        ]           ~~~~^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:84:9: note: forward declaration of 'struct termios2'
[        ]           struct termios2 *term = (struct termios2 *) data;
[        ]                  ^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:88:20: error: use of undeclared identifier 'CBAUD'
[        ]           term->c_cflag &= ~CBAUD;
[        ]                             ^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:89:6: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct termios2'
[        ]           term->c_cflag |= BOTHER;
[        ]           ~~~~^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:84:9: note: forward declaration of 'struct termios2'
[   +2 ms]           struct termios2 *term = (struct termios2 *) data;
[   +1 ms]                  ^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:89:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BOTHER'
[        ]           term->c_cflag |= BOTHER;
[        ]                            ^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:90:6: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct termios2'
[        ]           term->c_ispeed = term->c_ospeed = speed;
[        ]           ~~~~^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:84:9: note: forward declaration of 'struct termios2'
[        ]           struct termios2 *term = (struct termios2 *) data;
[   +1 ms]                  ^
[   +1 ms]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:90:23: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct termios2'
[        ]           term->c_ispeed = term->c_ospeed = speed;
[        ]                            ~~~~^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:84:9: note: forward declaration of 'struct termios2'
[        ]           struct termios2 *term = (struct termios2 *) data;
[        ]                  ^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:97:9: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'struct termiox'
[        ]           return sizeof(struct termiox);
[        ]                  ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[   +2 ms]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:97:23: note: forward declaration of 'struct termiox'
[   +1 ms]           return sizeof(struct termiox);
[        ]                                ^
[   +2 ms]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:105:15: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct termiox'
[   +1 ms]           *rts = (termx->x_cflag & RTSXOFF);
[        ]                   ~~~~~^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:102:9: note: forward declaration of 'struct termiox'
[        ]           struct termiox *termx = (struct termiox *) data;
[        ]                  ^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:105:27: error: use of undeclared identifier 'RTSXOFF'
[        ]           *rts = (termx->x_cflag & RTSXOFF);
[        ]                                    ^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:106:15: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct termiox'
[        ]           *cts = (termx->x_cflag & CTSXON);
[        ]                   ~~~~~^
[   +1 ms]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:102:9: note: forward declaration of 'struct termiox'
[        ]           struct termiox *termx = (struct termiox *) data;
[        ]                  ^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:106:27: error: use of undeclared identifier 'CTSXON'
[        ]           *cts = (termx->x_cflag & CTSXON);
[        ]                                    ^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:107:15: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct termiox'
[        ]           *dtr = (termx->x_cflag & DTRXOFF);
[        ]                   ~~~~~^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:102:9: note: forward declaration of 'struct termiox'
[        ]           struct termiox *termx = (struct termiox *) data;
[        ]                  ^
[        ]   C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/third_party/libserialport/linux_termios.c:107:27: error: use of undeclared identifier 'DTRXOFF'
[        ]           *dtr = (termx->x_cflag & DTRXOFF);
[        ]                                    ^
[        ]   fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
[        ]   20 errors generated.
[        ]   ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[   +1 ms]   C++ build system [build] failed while executing:
[        ]       @echo off
[        ]       "C:\\Users\\lucam\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\cmake\\3.18.1\\bin\\ninja.exe" ^
[        ]         -C ^
[        ]         "C:\\Users\\lucam\\AppData\\Local\\Pub\\Cache\\hosted\\pub.dev\\flutter_libserialport-0.3.0\\android\\.cxx\\Debug\\134n544x\\arm64-v8a" ^
[        ]         serialport
[        ]     from C:\Users\lucam\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_libserialport-0.3.0\android
[        ] * Try:
[        ] > Run with --debug option to get more log output.
[        ] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

**/Users/nameofuser/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_libserialport-0.3.0/android/libserialport/config.h**

**modify this file on line 57 to #undef HAVE_STRUCT_TERMIOX**

It works for me